# Keep getting 'Multiple Root Tags' Error

Tags: java, android-layout, android-studio, tags, root

I reviewed other similar questions about this problem, but none seem to be as bad as mine apparently. This is code from my res/layout/activity_signup.xml. The error keeps showing up next to the first bracket at . What silly thing am I missing this time?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="co.jessicagallego.neo.SignupActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_signup" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="56dp"
android:paddingLeft="24dp"
android:paddingRight="24dp">

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<!--  Name Label -->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/input_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:hint="Name" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<!-- Email Label -->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Email" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<!-- Password Label -->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="Password"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<!-- Signup Button -->
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:text="Create Account"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/link_login"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:text="Already a member? Login"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dip"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have two root tags in your XML, the first one is the `CoordinatorLayout` and the second one is the `ScollView`.

The Android SDK supports only one root tag in your XML. To fix this issue you can merge both tags you are using in a single root tag like the following:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <CoordinatorLayout>
    </CoordinatorLayout>

    <ScrollView>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or you can put one of the root tags inside the other according to how you want to build your view, for example:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>

    <ScrollView>
    </ScrollView>

</CoordinatorLayout>
```